# Array of arrays with ints

Tags: objective-c, c

How would you go about storing a 2 dimensional array of ints as a class variable?

If you want an array of ints you go:

**Class declaration**

```
int * myInts;
```

**Implementation**

```
int ints[3] = {1,2,3};
myInts = ints;
```

But what if you want to store an array of arrays with ints?

Like this:

```
 int ints[3][3] = {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}};
```

I don't wanna limit the size of the arrays in the class declaration so I guess I have to go with pointers, but how?

Comment: Did you try `int ** myInts;`?

Comment: Michael Kerlin: Sorry for not beeing as smart as you :/

Comment: Daniel R Hick: How would you then fill this double pointer with actual ints? you use malloc(sizeof(int)*numInts) if you have an ordinary pointer, but what do I do with this? int ** myInts = malloc(sizeof(??)*numArrs);

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824363/dynamic-allocation-deallocation-of-2d-3d-arrays) or many many other posts you can find in StackOverflow just by searching `2d array allocation C`

Comment: Thanks, again, sorry for my inability to succeed at life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this is my conclusion:

**Class declaration**

```
 int ** ints;
```

**Implementation**

```
 int rows = 2;
 int cols = 5;

 ints = (int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
 ints[0] = (int*)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));

 ints[0][0] = 123;
 ints[0][1] = 456;
 ints[0][2] = 789;
 // etc
```

This is my own interpretation of links provided in comments and my C skills are pretty low so take that into consideration ;) Maybe there are better ways to put in multiple numbers at a time with {123,456,789} or something, but that is beyond my requirements for now!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically allocate memory, in other words define the size of the arrays at runtime, then you need to declare the array as a pointer, malloc it, and then add another array of ints to each index at runtime.  You can't really declare and dynamically allocate at the class level.  If you are using cocoa/iphone sdk you can use NSMutableArray.

You could also create your own class that constructs a two dimensional array and exposes methods to push and pop int objects like [IntegerArray push:x,y,n];

Here's and example of using a [double reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570447/why-we-used-double-and-triple-pointer-in-objective-c-or-c-language) as Daniel R Hicks pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote sample for you:

```
int N = 10, M = 15;
NSMutableArray *ints = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:N]; // array[N][M]
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:M];
    for (int j=0; j<M; j++)
    {
        [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(i+1)*(j+1)]];
    }
    [ints addObject:arr];
}
// print
for (int i=0; i<[ints count]; i++)
{
    NSString *line = @"";
    NSMutableArray *arr = [ints objectAtIndex:i];
    for (int j=0; j<[arr count]; j++)
        line = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", line, [arr objectAtIndex:j]];
    NSLog(@"%@", line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is for a game so I don't wanna use a bunch of objects if I don't have to, for performance.

Comment: So do you need C-style realization?