# What is char ** in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is double star?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604099/what-is-double-star)

I am fairly new to C, and have come across this statement

```
typedef char **TreeType
```

I have a pretty good idea of what typedef does, but I have never seen char** before.  I know that char* is a char array or similiar to a string.  Im not sure if char** is a 2d char array or if it is the pointer to a character array.  I have looked around but cannot find what it is.  If you could please explain what a char** is or point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604099/what-is-double-star

Answer (score 35):

Technically, the `char*` is not an array, but a pointer to a `char`.

Similarly, `char**` is a pointer to a `char*`.  Making it a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

C and C++ both define arrays behind-the-scenes as pointer types, so yes, this structure, in all likelihood, is array of arrays of `char`s, or an array of strings.

Answer (score 7):

It is a pointer to a pointer, so yes, in a way it's a 2D character array.  In the same way that a `char*` could indicate an array of `char`s, a `char**` could indicate that it points to and array of `char*`s.

Answer (score 4):

well, `char *` means a pointer point to char, it is different from char array.

```
char amessage[] = "this is an array";  /* define an array*/
char *pmessage = "this is a pointer"; /* define a pointer*/
```

And, `char **` means a pointer point to a char pointer.

You can look some books about details about pointer and array.

Comment: In your example, `amessage` is still a pointer, which points to the beginning of your statically-sized `char` array.  The syntax `<type>*` is often indicative of an array, despite `<type>*` being, by itself, a pointer.

Comment: @ktodisco This example is from K&R. `amessage` is an array, just big enough to hold the sequence of characters and `\0` that initializes it.

Comment: If you look at the disassembly for those two statements, you will find they are both, at their core, pointers.  I'll also refer you to the second post [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10/).

Comment: @kevintodisco array can decay to a pointer, but they are not the same. Regarding your second comment(assembly language), it's about the implementation, not the language standard.