# How can I create a pointer for an array of strings?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am new to C and not sure how to pass pointers/addresses properly when it comes to chars/strings. I can't get my head around these "strings", about how to master the pointers.

I basically want to pass the address of the array "a" defined below to an arbitrary function, but I don't know how to define the pointer for this array.

Please help me!

I have the following code:

```
void change(char** a){
    a[0][0]='k';    //that should change a inside main
}

void main() {
    char a[2][3];
    char *tempWord;
    tempWord="sa";
    a[0]=tempWord;
    a[1]=tempWord;
    change(&a);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about [`char **`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/604099/2970947)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I can't understand that properly either, I ve heard that is the same as an array of arrays of chars. I just want to modify the array inside another function bassically.

Comment: *I ve heard that is the same as an array of arrays of chars.* And what do you think a `char a[2][3];` is? You should show your function, describe your desired behavior and show us an attempt at **that**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I hope that s better, I m trying to pass the address of that array of "strings".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a `char[2][3]` so you can pass a `char (*)[2][3]` to your `change` function. To copy `tempWord` into your `char[][]` you can use `strncpy`. Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, that might look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void change(char (*a)[2][3]) {
    *a[0][0] = 'k';
}

int main() {
    char a[2][3];
    char *tempWord = "sa";
    strncpy(a[0], tempWord, strlen(tempWord));
    strncpy(a[1], tempWord, strlen(tempWord));
    change(&a);
}
```

*Is there any other definition of pointer other than `char(*a)[2][3]`?*

I guess you really did want a `char **`; you will need to `malloc` and `free` your memory for that. Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void change(char **a) {
    a[0][0]='k';
}

int main() {
    char **a;
    char *tempWord = "sa";
    a = malloc(2 * sizeof(char **));
    a[0] = malloc(strlen(tempWord) * sizeof(char *));
    a[1] = malloc(strlen(tempWord) * sizeof(char *));
    strncpy(a[0], tempWord, strlen(tempWord));
    strncpy(a[1], tempWord, strlen(tempWord));
    change(a);
    printf("%s\n", a[0]);
    free(a[1]);
    free(a[0]);
    free(a);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other definition of pointer other than char(*a)[2][3]? Because I would like to pass the array address without knowing its sizes.@ElliottFrisch

Comment: Another question regarding free function. If we only free a[0] and a[1]  do we have to free "a" as well as "a" just holds the pointers a[0] and a[1] ?@ElliottFrisch Thank you!

Comment: If you `malloc` three times, you need to `free` three times.

Comment: Should it not be a[0] = malloc((strlen(tempWord)+1) * sizeof(char *));? as you allocate memory for that '\0'? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: In the first example it should be `(*a)[0][0] = k`; . In this exact case (all indices are 0) it doesn't matter , but it would matter if they used any other indices.

Comment: The second program causes undefined behaviour, `printf("%s\n"` should only have a null-terminated string as argument and `a[0]` is not null-terminated. Also all of the malloc calls request the wrong size. (I'd recommend standard pattern `p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );`

Comment: @M.M, you said "p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );", what is the type of p ?

Comment: @BurLeXyOOnuTz it doesn't matter, which is why this form is good

Comment: @M.M, sorry I meant does p have to be pointer of a pointer, or literally anything? Because if char* p=malloc(3* sizeof (char)) would sound fair?