# Is char** a pointer to an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

From my understanding, `char* X` is a variable that points to a single character or a character array (string) in C.

`char**` is a pointer which points to another pointer which finally points to a single character or a character array.

if `int**` is equivalent to creating a multidimensional array, why can't I create an array of strings in C using `char**`?

```
const char** day = {
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
};
```

Here `*day` would point to the array itself and `**day` would point to the first element of the array "Sunday"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is double star (eg. NSError \*\*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604099/what-is-double-star-eg-nserror)

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves let's not confuse ppl with objective-c here

Comment: And `int **` is not an equivalent of 2d array - far from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `char* X` is a variable that points to a single character or a character array (string) in C.

No, it is a variable that contains the *address* of a single character. That single character may or may not be the beginning of a null terminated string.

Thus `char**` points at a `char*` that points at a character.

> if `int**` is equivalent to creating a multidimensional array

It is not. `int**` has nothing to do with multi-dimensional arrays.

> why can't I create an array of strings in C using `char**`?

Because a `char**` is not an array nor can it, strictly speaking, point at one.

---

A `char*` can be used to point at a null terminated string. So if you want an array of strings, you need an array of `char*`. Which can for example be written as:

```
char* day[] = { ... };
```

Now as it turns out, a `char**` can be used to point at the address of the *first item* of this array, `&day[0]`, since that is a `char*`. This often make people confuse `char**` for multi-dimensional arrays, because it is valid to do this:

```
char* day[] = { "Sunday", ... };
char** week = &day[0];
printf("%c", week[0][0]); // prints 'S'
```

But that does not make `char**` an array, nor does it make it a 2D array.

You can also use `char**` to dynamically allocate a look-up table of strings, where each string has a variable length:

```
char** week = malloc(7 * sizeof(char*));
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
  week[i] = malloc( ... );
}
```

Here again, the `char**` points at the first item of a 1D array of `char*`. It is *not* a 2D array, it does not point at one. That it allows `week[i][j]` syntax is irrelevant, it is still not an array (and `[]` is never actually used on array types, [Do pointers support “array style indexing”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing)).

More info: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 6):

*why can't I create an array of strings in C using char**?* yes you can create. Correct way is to use **array of char pointers** not the double `char**` pointer as you did. For e.g

```
const char* day[7] = {
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
};
```

Above, `day` is *array of char pointers* and its each element is *character pointer* and each elements needs to point to valid address. Here `day[0]` is character pointer & its pointing to string literal `sunday` which is valid address.

Its also possible via `char**` but not the way as you did. For e.g

```
char **day = {"sunday", "Monday" };
```

here problem is you haven't allocated memory for `day[0]`, `day[1]` to hold some string literal like `sunday` & so on.

First allocate memory for `day` like below

```
char **day = malloc(NUM_OF_DAYS * sizeof(*day)); /* define NUM_OF_DAYS as 7 */
```

And then allocate memory for `day[0]`, `day[1]` etc.

```
for(int index =0 ; index < NUM_OF_DAYS; index++) {
   day[index] = malloc(MAX_DAY_SIZE * sizeof(**day)); /* define this MACRO */
}
```

And then you scan the data at run time.

Comment: "here problem is you haven't allocated memory for day[0], day[1]" No it isn't. The string literals are already allocated in read-only memory. The problem is that a `char**` can only be assigned to point at a single `char*`. A `char**` is a _scalar_ (single item) not an _aggregate_ (container), so you can't initialize it like that with `{ a, b }`. It's a syntax error and not related to dynamic allocation. You can however initialize it to point at a compound literal array: `const char** day = (const char* []){"Sunday", "Monday"};`. You only need to malloc if you need read/write memory.